# How to show "From Name" in Email Template

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert, singleemailmessage, merge-field

I want to show specific From Name in the email template as I have more than one record in the Org wide address. Can anyone help how to do it?
Note : I am always getting the current logged in user name through user.name

[image]

[image]